# Customizing text editor with css

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using OceanWP theme. I'm trying to customize a text editor that has many lines of text. I have 2 questions about how to use css:

1. How can you prevent extra space after every line?
2. How can you specify font colors for different lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase or decrease space between lines by setting line-height.

```html
textarea {line-height: 1.5;} */ Half a line space between each line
```

You cannot change the color of a line inside a textarea with CSS. You can do it in Javascript though.

Comment: I'm actually using Elementor and took me a while to figure out how to complete your suggestion. Then, I realized that my problem is not so much caused by the css code but by Elementor adding extra space after every paragraph. I'll have to post this question separately in the Elementor forum. [Using Javascript is definitely beyond my current intentions/skills]. Thanks.